# The representation of p-norm of $f$ using Schwartz class.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, schwartz-space

For $1＜p＜\infty$ and the conjugate $p'$, show that the $p$- norm of $f$ is written as
$$\| f \|_p=\sup\left\{\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}fg\right| : g \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n), \|g\|_{p'}=1\right\}\cdots (\ast)$$ The hint is to use $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)\subset \mathcal L^{p'}(\mathbb R^n)$ dense, where $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is Schwartz class.

I know that a similar representation of $\|f\|_{p}$ :
$$\| f \|_p=\sup\left\{\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}fg\right| : g \in \mathcal L^{p'}(\mathbb R^n), \|g\|_{p'}= 1\right\}.$$

Let $$A_1=\left\{\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}fg\right| : g \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n), \|g\|_{p'}=1\right\},$$
$$ A_2=\left\{\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}fg\right| : g \in \mathcal L^{p'}(\mathbb R^n), \|g\|_{p'}=1\right\}$$

Since $A_1 \subset A_2$, $\sup A_1\leqq\sup A_2 $ is OK. I have to see the opposite.

To see that $\sup A_1$ is an upper bound of $A_2$, let $g \in \mathcal L^{p'}$ with $\|g\|_{p'}=1.$

Since $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)\subset \mathcal L^{p'}(\mathbb R^n)$ dense, there is $\{g_k\}\subset\mathcal S$ s.t. $\|g_k-g\|_{p'}\to 0.$

From here, I don't know how to deduce $(\ast)$.

Thanks for the help. Other approach is also welcomed.

Comment: For $f\in\mathcal L^p$, $g\in \mathcal L^{p'}$, and $h\in \mathcal S$ with $\|g-h\|_{p'} \le \varepsilon/\|f\|_p$ you get from Hölder's inequality $\left|\int fg\right|\le \left|\int fh\right|+\|f(g-h)\|_1 \le  \left|\int fh\right|+\|f\|_p\|(g-h)\|_{p'}\le  \left|\int fh\right|+\varepsilon$

Comment: Does your $h$ satisfy $\|h\|_{p'}=1$ ？ @Jochen